# Autocorrelation robust errors with plm and vcovHC

Tags: r, panel-data, autocorrelation, plm

I have a panel dataset where I suspect a serial correlation.
I found the `vcovHC` function in `plm` package which should solve both heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation.

But in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plm/versions/2.6-3/topics/vcovHC.plm), they say

> All types assume no intragroup (...) correlation between errors and allow for heteroskedasticity across groups (...).

I am not a native English speaker so it might be just a misunderstanding, but I thought, that the usual problem is the correlation of errors of the same individual through time.
And that this function should solve it. But if I understand the documentation correctly, those methods assume no intragroup correlation, which is precisely what I said I want to solve, right?

So the function is not suitable for situations when errors of one individual are correlated? What is it used for then?

Comment: "Intragroup" means between different individuals.

Comment: Wiktionary says Taking place within a group, especially within a social group. 
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intragroup

Answer (score 0):

Very humbly, since quantitative methods are not my strength, I think you might want to check the clustering offered by the function vcovHC. I got confused with that phrasing too. But I applied the clustering by group (`c="group"`) and, if I understand it right, it checks for serial correlation within the unit which in my case are firms. I was not so sure because I did not know how the function groups data, but I guess it just takes the grouping that is modelled in your plm function. In my case:

```
TEST <- plm(Y ~ 1 + X1 + X2 + ... +
                     data = THEDATA, 
                     index = c("FIRM", "Year"), 
                     model = "random")
```

So, if you want autocorrelation-robust errors with `plm` and `vcovHC`, considering "...that the usual problem is the correlation of errors of the same individual through time." You would need to apply:

```
summary(TEST, vcov=vcovHC(TEST, method="arellano", type="HC1", c="group"))$coe
```

I hope my remarks are correct.